# How are self-invoking functions hoisted?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Please see this code example:

```
var myFunc = function () {
  alert("hello world");
})();
```

This is a function expression, which is not hoisted. So my presumption here is that it runs only when the code gets to its actual position within the code. Is this true?

Comment: That applies to every function. It only executes when it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is a function expression, which is not hoisted.

Yes. Function expressions are not hoisted (self-invoking or otherwise).

What's more, there are no references to the function stored *anywhere*, so there isn't anything to hoist in the first place.

---

> So my presumption here is that it runs only…

Function declarations are hoisted, but that has nothing to do with when they are run. Just when the variable name matching the function name gets it's value (so it can be used to call the function).

A function only runs when it is called.

In your code, then is when the `()` after the function body are processed.

---

The `var` declaration of `myFunc`, like all `var` declarations, will be hosted. It will get an initial value of `undefined` and then, when the function runs, it will get the return value (also `undefined`) of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct.

> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function expressions before you define them

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function